# Topic proportion of different variables other than documents

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I'm running a stm in reddit data. I've categorized the reddit posts into different hate speech like anti-asian, anti-black etc. i want to calculate the probability of given hate speech being a particular topic.

for instance, i want results to be like : 30% of topic 1 is anti-asian and 70% of topic 1 is anti-black and this continues for all the numbers of topics i have.

Also, i want another table with the results like anti-asian is 5% of all the topics i have, and 95% of topics are anti-black.

```
posts <- c("i dislike asian", "i dislike black")
anti-asian <- TRUE, FALSE
anti_black <- FAlSE, TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected probability is the relative abundance of that binary occurrence vector, which can be calculated as follows:

```r
anti_asian <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
table(anti_asian)[["TRUE"]]/length(anti_asian)
#> [1] 0.6666667
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>